# Trigger on update in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I successfully executed this code :

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER dept_no_exist
 BEFORE insert OR UPDATE on emp
 for each row
 DECLARE
    x_count NUMBER;
 begin
    select count(*) into x_count from dept where deptno=:new.deptno;
    if(x_count=0) then
            insert into dept values(:new.deptno,'A SAISIR','A SAISIR');
    end if;
 end;
 /
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to insert the n-uplet (`:new.deptno,'A SAISIR','A SAISIR'`) into the table `deptno` when a employee (table emp) is affected to departement that doesn't exist in the table dept. My trigger works for an insert query but doesn't for an update query.

Comment: you are logically wrong, while updating the `count(*)` won't be 0. hence it will not `insert` in `dept` table

Comment: Ok, but why does it work for the insert statement then ? because I've put "BEFORE" for the two statements

Comment: @Exhausted - why would counting against `dept` be affected by the statement type against `emp`?

Comment: Do you get an error? Is deptno a foreign key, perhaps?

Comment: @AlexPoole That user wants to say. While updating, there will be a record (which i guess, also a foriegn key in employee table) in `dept` table, hence `count` will give `>0`. hence insert will not happen which is under `if` statement

Comment: Actually the counting against dept is here to check if the new employee inserted into emp (or updated) belongs to a departement that exists (deptno in table dept), if the dept doesn't exist, it is created with : insert into dept values(:new.deptno,'A SAISIR','A SAISIR'); . I get no error but the insert is not executed when I update table emp with a deptno that doesn't exist in table dept; Ok, how can I change that ?

Comment: here another thing is, you use `BEFORE`  timing, that might be reason, use `AFTER` trigger instead

Comment: Yes, using AFTER instead of BEFORE solved my problem, thanks, post it into an answer Exhausted, so that I can validate you answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER dept_no_exist
 AFTER insert OR UPDATE on emp
 for each row
 DECLARE
    x_count NUMBER;
 begin
    select count(*) into x_count from dept where deptno=:new.deptno;
    if(x_count=0) then
            insert into dept values(:new.deptno,'A SAISIR','A SAISIR');
    end if;
 end;
 /
```

Row level triggers can access new and existing values of columns using the *:NEW.column-name* and *:OLD.column-name* references, bearing in mind the following restrictions.

- **Row-level INSERT triggers :** Only ":NEW" references are possible as
  there is no existing row.
- **Row-level UPDATE triggers :** Both ":NEW" and
  ":OLD" references are possible. ":NEW" represents the new value
  presented in the DML statement that caused the trigger to fire.
  ":OLD" represents the existing value in the column, prior to the
  update being applied.
- **Row-level DELETE triggers :** Only ":OLD"
  references are possible as there is no new data presented in the
  triggering statement, just the existing row that is to be deleted.

here :NEW values are only obtained during `AFTER` timing trigger.

refer here for more information

http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/database-triggers-overview.php

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is just an assignment for a SQL course, I would strongly advise against doing what you are trying to do. If it is an assignment for a SQL course, they are teaching you terrible concepts.

What you are attempting to do is catch an insert or update of employee data. If the dept number given does not match any department listed in the Department table, you want to create a department with that dept number.

Absolutely terrible, no good, very bad idea. Under those circumstances, you *want* the insert or update to fail. You want the user to gaze thoughtfully at the error message and say, "Wow, I guess I should create that department *then* assign employees to it."

The overwhelming majority of the time, however, he will say something like, "Oops. That was dept number 17, not 170." So you will have created a department 170 in the database when there is no such department. A well-designed app will in this situation ask the user if he wants to create a new department. If this was the first employee to be assigned to a new department, then the department will be created and the assignment can continue. If the user entered a wrong value, he has the opportunity to correct it and continue.

If there is no user, if this is coming in from some batched source, you still don't want to be creating a new department. In that case, you could write out the problematic employee data to a log table to have someone examine later.

You want your database to make it as easy as possible for your users to do their jobs. You want to make it as difficult as possible to make mistakes. Making it easier to enter spurious data into the database is not a goal you should be working toward.